# Is this dirt or the natural finish of my composite deck?

Tags: deck, outdoor, cleaning, composite

Update: Added two photos of the bottom of the deck

I washed my composite wood deck with:

- 1 gallon of water
- 1 cup vinegar
- 1/4 cup baking soda
- Soft bristle brush

I thought it would remove what looks like dirt on the deck boards (see attached photos)

Now I am starting to think its just the natural look of the board. I'm not sure what brand the previous owners installed.

If its dirt I thought I might need a more aggressive cleaner or some light power washing. I think its been a couple of years since its had some maintenance

wood board close up

[image]

wood board

[image]

Bottom of deck Screenshot 3

[image: Bottom of composite deck board]

Closeup of deck from the bottom Screenshot 4

[image: close up of bottom of composite deck board]

Comment: look at the bottom of the boards, if they are also "dirty", that's probably just how they are.

Comment: Also, composite does degrade, so while it may have appeared smooth when new, the exposure to the elements may have caused it to lose tiny particles from the surface, leaving that roughened look.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I added screenshots of the bottom of the deck to the original post as an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a perfectly normal faux-woodgrain brown composite deck.

Comment: I guess by normal you mean it hasn’t been damaged. It seems like there is a layer of dirt.

Comment: @pmagunia   If you have a hidden section you can test a small piece with extra pressure to see if there is a difference.